# Error while debug/deploy a Xamarin Windows Phone app on the device

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I am starting develop on Xamarin.Forms Platform: I have installed it as Visual Studio's plugin. When i try to create a simple default project and then deploy it on the device (attached via USB) I obtain this message:

> DEP4503: It has been installed the maximum number of app development.
>   These apps are installed on the device when I started in 
>   Visual Studio or when using the deployment tool app.
>   Uninstall one of the app and try again. 0x-2130509543: Exception from
>   HRESULT: 0x81030119 HelloXamarin.WinPhone

But, I have not installed any app before! Is it 0 maximun number?!

P.S. I have a regular Developer Account. The device is unlocked for Developer Mode.

Thanks,
Regards!

Comment: You can have an unlimited number of apps on your developer-unlocked phone from the Windows Store, but there is a limit of 10 developer apps that can be loaded onto a dev-unlocked phone at any time. Once you have reached that limit, you must remove at least one of them from your developer phone in order to load another one onto the phone. This is a simple solution and doesn't require unregistering & reregistering your phone.

Comment: If you've had recent permission level changes or are changing to a new developer account, you may need to restart the phone to clear the old permissions after removing it from your DevCenter account.

Comment: @Abhimanyu Yes, but I load only one app (not 10), so why it notice me that I am over the limit?

Comment: Furthermore, although I have unlocked the phone, it does not appear in the list of unlocked devices on the page of my developer account.